# Why there is water produced on the phone if we keep our phone in our pocket for a longer time?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, water, humidity

one day I kept my phone in my pant pocket, I haven't opened it for a long time. My phone is covered with a plastic case. So why the phone is  getting wet when I observed it after some time even though plastics are non conductive towards heat. When I kept my phone in pant pocket without the case then no wet has been observed by me on the phone

Whether it is due to heat of the phone or the sweat of mine due to the heat released by the phone or the heat is mainly due to heat from the screen of the phone (as some background apps were running at the time)  which is open and it is not close by any non-conductive material

Comment: was this a one time observation? It could be possible you closed the plastic on a very humid atmosphere, or already water was somehow in the bag,

Comment: no its moderate temperature

Comment: in both of the two observation

Comment: what about humidity?